# Does dayjs support ordinals in month? (Feb. instead of Feb, for germany language)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, dayjs

I am trying to get following representation of a month in German: `Feb.`

I tried so far:

`'Do MMM YYYY'`

and

`dayjs(date).format('Do MMM YYYY')`

With `momentjs` you used to get `1. Feb. 2012` but with `dayjs` I get `1. Feb 2012`. I tried `MMMo` but didn't work.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `MMM` and add the `.` as a string? Or are you going for something like `Feb. 2012`?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work because the abbreviation of März is März, without the dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no format supporting a conditional '.' for cases such as the german "März". The cleanest workaround I could come up with is the following:

```js
const date = dayjs("2019-03-24").locale("de")
date.format(`MMM${[2, 5, 6].includes(date.$M) ? '' : '.'} YYYY`)
```

This checks if the provided date is a month with 4 character (März, Juni or Juli) and does not add the '.' in such cases. All other months will be shortened with a '.' at the end, e.g. "Jan.", "Feb." etc..